# Why do menu items blink twice when selected?

Tags: macbook-pro

I wanted to know why while clicking on an written item (quit, hide, option...) the item in question blink twice very fast and then do the action we wanted?

Thanks

Comment: It may help you get a response if you change the subject to show a summary of what the question is

Comment: Is there a deeper question here? This is just a design decision that Apple had made it years ago and continues to use presumably because they think it's the best experience for the user.

Comment: @bmike I don't know if that's the OP's case, but I can imagine that switchers from Windows to OS X may be surprised by or even bothered with visual cues like this. So no, there is no deeper question here, but I think it is still a valid question that expresses curiosity on why this happens.

Comment: @jaume Cool - I just wanted to be sure we were answering Melvish's issue if it wasn't the one we all assumed was the obvious question. If the OP had added that back story, we could be more sure about their intent. As it reads - there's a bit of guessing that can happen by people trying to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a visual cue that you have selected that menu item.

It is described in Apple's "OS X Human Interface Guidelines" under Menu Behavior (page 134):

> When the user chooses a menu item, it blinks briefly to confirm the
> user’s choice and then performs the action.

(Note that this document has been retired and is no longer available for download, but a copy is available at https://issuu.com/hyungjoonjun/docs/osxhiguidelines)

OS X provides other visual cues: when you press a key shortcut, for example <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the menu bar menu where that key shortcut is listed, in our example `Edit`:

[image]

is highlighted for a fraction of a second.

Comment: And in older versions of "classic" Mac System Software you could change the number of blinks and/or turn it off. I guess that preference didn't make it thru the transition to OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of times the menu item blinks or is highlighted used to be selectable in older versions of the MacOS.  I haven't found a means to change it in OS X or later.